# Bash prompt changed in terminal

Tags: bash, command-prompt

Suddendly my bash prompt changed to

`[80-254-70-241]myusername @ ~ $`

when in my home directory.

I have the following command in my .bash_profile `export PS1="\[\033[32m\][\h]\u @ \W \$\[\033[0m\]`

I think the expression in square brackets supposed to be the name of the current directory.

What does this number `80-254-70-241` mean and how do I change it back?

Comment: it's related to hostname don't do anything inside .bashrc.

Comment: post the output of `cat /etc/hostname`

Answer (score 3):

The string "80-254-70-241" comes from the parameter "\h", which denotes your hostname.  I think you got an IP and a hostname from DHCP so the prompt changed accordingly.

If you think this is annoying, you can replace "\h" with your preferred hostname (hardcoded).